# How to detect internet connectivity on a non gateway interface linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, routes, network-programming

I have a Linux system with 2 NICs, one of which (`eth0`) is the default gateway. The other (`eth1`) is not a default gateway. Both have network connections with internet connectivity - so the link state is up.

I want to periodically check on `eth1` to see if Internet traffic can be routed through it. Whilst I am checking `eth1`, I need to keep my Internet traffic routing through `eth0` uninterrupted. If I can make a connection through `eth1`, I will then switch my default gateway (as that is my cheaper connection).

I am trying to check the connection by opening a socket, binding it to `eth1` and connecting to a port. I have used `8.8.8.8:443` for my example.

```
bool canConnect(const string interface)
{
    bool        result = false;
    sockaddr_in host;
    timeval     timeout;

    int sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
        return result;

    struct ifreq ifr;
    ::strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface.c_str(), IFNAMSIZ);

    int res = setsockopt(_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr));
    if (res < 0)
    {
        ::close(sock);
        return result;
    }

    int reuse = 1;
    if (::setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        ::close(sock);
        return result;
    }

    ::inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", host.sin_addr);
    host.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    host.sin_port        = htons(443);

    if (::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&host , sizeof(host)) < 0)
    {
        int error = errno;
        if (error != EINPROGRESS) // socket is non-blocking
        {
            ::close(sock);
            return result;
        }
    }

    fd_set writeSet;
    fd_set readSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    FD_ZERO(&writeSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &readSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &writeSet);

    timeout.tv_sec  = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int res = ::select(sock + 1, &readSet, &writeSet, NULL, &timeout);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        ::close(sock);
        return result;
    }

    else if (res == 0)
    {
        // function always exits here
        ::close(sock);
        return result;
    }

    else if (FD_ISSET(sock, &writeSet) || FD_ISSET(sock, &readSet))
    {
        int val;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(val);
        ::getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &val, &len);
        if (val == 0)
            result = true;
    }
    ::close(sock);

    return result;
}
```

When I run the code, `select()` always times out. I never manage to make a connection to `8.8.8.8:443`, even though `eth1` has Internet connectivity (I have proven this by switching the default gateway to `eth1` temporarily.

Am I missing some code, or do I need kernel options to make this work?

I have IP forwarding turn on.

Answer (score 0):

If `connect()` is successful and waiting, you should be checking `select()` for writable only, not readable at all.  This is stated in the [`connect()` mangage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> EINPROGRESS
>   The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be
>   completed immediately.  It is possible to `select(2)` or `poll(2)`
>   for completion **by selecting the socket for writing**.  After
>   `select(2)` **indicates writability**, use `getsockopt(2)` to read the
>   `SO_ERROR` option at level `SOL_SOCKET` to determine whether
>   `connect()` completed successfully (`SO_ERROR` is zero) or
>   unsuccessfully (`SO_ERROR` is one of the usual error codes
>   listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

Besides, a socket is readable only if there is inbound data to be read, but you are connecting to an HTTPS port, so there will never be any data to read in your example, as you are not sending an HTTPS handshake request.

Also, you should not be calling `select()` unless `connect()` actually fails with `EINPROGRESS`. If `connect()` returns 0, the connection was successful right way without blocking.  So, you should move your `select()` call inside your `if (connect < 0)` block after checking `errno`.

Also, you are not passing the correct socket to `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE)`.

Also, you are not passing the correct value to the `dst` parameter of `inet_pton()`.  You are passing it an `in_addr`, but it expects an `in_addr*` instead.

Also, there is no need to use `SO_REUSEADDR` in this example, since you are not `bind()`'ing to a specific local IP/port pair before calling `connect()`.

Try something more like this:

```
bool canConnect(const string &interface)
{
    bool result = false;

    int sock = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
        return result;

    struct ifreq ifr;
    ::strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, interface.c_str(), IFNAMSIZ);

    int res = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof(ifr));
    if (res < 0)
    {
        ::close(sock);
        return result;
    }

    sockaddr_in host;
    ::inet_pton(AF_INET, "8.8.8.8", &(host.sin_addr));
    host.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    host.sin_port        = htons(443);

    result = (::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&host, sizeof(host)) == 0);
    if (!result)
    {
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) // socket is non-blocking
        {
            ::close(sock);
            return result;
        }

        fd_set writeSet;
        timeval timeout;

        FD_ZERO(&writeSet);
        FD_SET(sock, &writeSet);

        timeout.tv_sec  = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        res = ::select(sock + 1, NULL, &writeSet, NULL, &timeout);
        if (res <= 0)
        {
            ::close(sock);
            return result;
        }

        int val;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(val);
        ::getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &val, &len);
        result = (val == 0);
    }

    ::close(sock);
    return result;
}
```

That being said, `8.8.8.8` is a DNS server, so why would you think it is running an HTTPS server as well?  Make sure you are connecting to an actual HTTPS server (why HTTPS and not HTTP?).   You might consider using `getaddrinfo()` instead to get the IP address for `www.google.com` (or any other commonly used webserver) instead of hard-coding `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Thanks @remy-lebeau. I have checked your comments - I think most were typos when copying my sample code.
I have removed the read checking in select, and move the select to within the connect < 0 block.
I was using 8.8.8.8 as I have already checked that port 443 is open, and the code works if I add eth1 as a default gateway. Eventually, I will use a web server that I have control of.


The problem is, I want to check for connectivity before making eth1 the default gateway so I know it will work when I switch.